# How to redirect without breaking hierarchy?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect single page without breaking the slug that this single page affects. I've tried to set it up myself and even work with my host, but haven't had success.

This is my latest attempt. However, this breaks the pages that uses this slug, when I just want it to affect a singular page. I've tried different expressions but nothing seems to work.

```
Redirect 301 /question$ https://website.com/support
```

I would like this page to redirect this way:
https://website.com/question ==> https://website.com/support

While this works, the pages that uses /question as a slug breaks:
https://website.com/question/topic ==> 404 Error with redirection in place

The "$" expression should only redirect if the page ends with /question, but it's also affecting the slug in other pages. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you.